# How to send text to a group of numbers (group text) using Twilio API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twilio

I'm using c# to send a text message to a group of phone numbers.I'm able to send it to one phone number, but I don't see any documentation to do it for multiple numbers. I'm not sure if I should use their conversations API to achieve that.

Here is what I did to send it to a phone number:
`

```
TwilioClient.Init(_settingService.TWilioAccountSid, _settingService.TwilioAuthToken);
            var twilioMessage = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                body: message,
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(from),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(to) 
               );
```

How to send the message to a list of nubmers?

Comment: Can't you put it in a loop?

Comment: A loop will send the message to each phone number, but I want to send the message as a group text.

Comment: Ok, that part was not so clear.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/group-texting-in-conversations

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio Conversations API has support for group MMS, but [Group MMS is currently not available for new customers](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/limitation-to-group-mms), so there's no way to currently do that unless you already have access to Group MMS.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I thought their Conversation API could do that, but no.